# "The second half of the second decade of the third millennium"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "The second half of the second decade of the third millennium"

I have difficulty understanding the phrase above. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

It means the time period from 2015 until 2020. Sometimes, pictures are "worth a thousand words":

[image]

Comment: Off by one errors...

Comment: @StephenS How so?

Comment: The third millennium is 2001-3000, second decade is 2011-2020, second half is 2016-2020.

Comment: Ah, you're one of [those people](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium#Debate_over_millennium_celebrations). ;) I'm not! It's not an error, but it is open to personal interpretation.

Comment: What years did the first millennium cover?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to look at this is to read it backward. Like how you read numbers by going from the largest to the smallest, you would understand this sentence by looking at the end - where the object of the sentence is - and working back from there.
So you have the third millennium. Ignoring other ways of counting years, that means 2001-3000. So we have 2xxx. Then it says the second decade. That would be 201x. Then it's just the second half, so just the second half of the 2010s.
I hope that makes sense! It's possible I made a silly math error but the breakdown should at least be sound.